# python-pandas install wants to remove R

Tags: python

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

When trying to install python-pandas 0.7.0-1, Synaptic wants to uninstall my complete R installation. This does not make any sense. Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what R is, but installing python-pandas on a default 12.04 installation installs a bunch of r-* stuff. It sounds like you may have R installed from somewhere else (like a PPA) and it is a version that is incompatible with the version of python-pandas in the official repo.